# Two threads deleting from a lock-free stack

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, stack, lock-free

I am referring to page 185 and 186 in C++ Concurrency in Action. They give the following code as a method for a lock-free stack:

```
void push(T const& data){
    node* const new_node = new node(data);
    new_node->next=head.load();
    while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));
}
```

and on P186 it says the following:

> Of course, now that you have a means of adding data to the stack, you
>   need a way of getting it off again. On the face of it, this is quite
>   simple:
>
> 1. Read the current value of `head`
> 2. Read `head->next`
> 3. Set `head` to `head->next`
> 4. Return the data from the retrieved node
> 5. Delete the retrieved node
>
> However, in the presence of multiple threads, this isn't so simple. If
>   there are two threads removing items from the stack they both might
>   read the same value of `head` at step 1. If one thread then proceeds
>   all the way through to step 5 before the other gets to step 2, the
>   second thread will be dereferencing a dangling pointer.

I thought that compare_exchange_weak() could be used to essentially complete step 2 and 3 atomically and the second thread could see that `head->next` is no longer valid?

I am surprised we cannot use CAS to solve the above problem??

Comment: Why would `head->next` be null? (To be honest, your question seems to far from sensible that I wonder if you understand the logic of this code at all.)

Comment: I made the assumption that dangling pointer meant pointing to an object which was now null. What is "so far from sensible" about my question?

Comment: No, dangling pointer means pointing to an object that has been removed from the stack and thus probably deleted. It's hard to answer your question because it's hard to figure out exactly where your misunderstanding is. (Isn't is obvious that even if steps 2 and 3 are done atomically, the value read at step 1 can be wrong when we get to step 2 if another thread changes it?)

Comment: Referring to the push() code I included in my Q- steps 1, 2 and 3 are similar to the code in line numbers 3, 4 and 4. Do you agree? So if the head was made invalid, is there no way we can put logic in the while(CAS) loop so thread 2 can detect this?

Comment: To solve the ABA problem we can include a counter in the node and then check the counter within the while loop, so why can't we "delete" a node by setting an atomic "isdeleted" data member and then check for this in the while loop?

Comment: Your questions don't really make any sense. There must be something fundamental you don't get. There are only certain atomic primitives that we have. We can't just make up an operation like "check if it's deleted and if not remove it by doing a compare and swap" and expect it to exist as a lock-free, atomic operation.

Comment: @user997112 Could you maybe post the code for `pop` you imagine would be correct using `compare_exchange_weak`? That would make answering the question much easier.

Comment: I am not sure why the author said what I quoted- but on P211 he says (for a lock-free queue) using a shared_ptr<> (so long as its lock free) for returning the data, compare_weak_exchange and atomic pointers is fullproof..... so I guess that kinda answers my original question? If you have atomic pointers and use a lock-free shared_ptr for T then it will work?

Answer (score 0):

When popping an item off, you don't change item->next, you change head to point to item->next.  **You are not allowed to change an item till you pop it off the list**.  If another thread changes item->next, it means they have popped it off the list, which means the ABA version will be different (i'm assuming you use an ABA check in linked lists like this) and probably (which is why you use ABA - because of the "probably" here) head will be different, so your CAS will fail.

Notes about ABA, if you never put an item back on the list once it's popped, and you never free any items (which would allow an item's memory to be reused and stuck back on the list), then you don't need the ABA check.  However, it only takes a few bits to implement ABA, because you only need as many versions as could possibly happen in the time it takes to pop an item off the list.  I like at least 16, but that might be cutting it close.  Every time you add an item change the ABA version.  Every time you remove an item, change the ABA version.

Other important notes.  Items in an atomic list like this are not meant to be traversed using the head/next that are being manipulated atomically.  This is because you never know if someone popped the item off and changed next.  I have found that if you change next to something else in the list, say to skip over an item, this can work in some situations.  Items in an atomic list like this are never meant to be added or removed anywhere other than the head of the list.  You cannot make this work (easily...never say never) with atomic operations.

Here is an example that works on msvc 2010.  This uses Microsoft's version of what volatile means.  You could use std::atomic if your compiler was iso.  NOTE the use of union.  union CAtomicLinkList is how we atomically set more than one field at a time.

```
template <typename T> class CAtomicListItem : public T {
  typedef CAtomicListItem<T> CItem;
public:
  CItem*      m_pNext;

  CItem()  : m_pNext(NULL)                               { }
  CItem(T &r) : T(r),  m_pNext(NULL)                     { }
};

template <typename T> union CAtomicLinkList {
  typedef CAtomicLinkList<T> CList;
  typedef CAtomicListItem<T> CItem;
public:
  struct {
    QWORD     m_pHead : 44,    // Addr of first item.  Windows only uses 8tb
                      :  4,    // extra space.
              m_nABA  : 16;    // Version to prevent ABA.  We don't need this 
                               // many bits so there is room for expansion.
  };
  QWORD        m_n64;          // atomically update this struct by CAS on this field.

  CList() : m_n64(0)                                     { }
  // These constructors are for making copies.  These cannot threadsafe 
  // update a shared instance.
  CList(volatile const CList& r) : m_n64(r.m_n64)        { }

  void Push(CItem *pItem) volatile {
    while (1) {
      CList Old(*this), New(Old);
      New.m_pHead = UINT_PTR(pItem);
      New.m_nABA++;  // whenever you change the list, change the version
      pItem->m_pNext = (CItem*)Old.m_pHead;
      if (CAS(&m_n64, Old.m_n64, New.m_n64))
        return; // success
    }
  }

  CItem* Pop() volatile {
    while (1) {
      CList Old(*this);
      if (!Old.m_pHead)
        return NULL;
      CList New(Old);
      CItem* pItem = (CItem*)Old.m_pHead;
      New.m_pHead = UINT_PTR(pItem->m_pNext);
      New.m_nABA++; // whenever you change the list, change the version
      if (CAS(&m_n64, Old.m_n64, New.m_n64))
        return pItem; // success
    }
  }
};

inline bool CAS(volatile WORD* p, const WORD nOld, const WORD nNew) {
  Assert(IsAlign16(p)); 
  return WORD(_InterlockedCompareExchange16((short*)p, nNew, nOld)) == nOld; 
}
inline bool CAS(volatile DWORD* p, const DWORD nOld, const DWORD nNew) {
  Assert(IsAlign32(p)); 
  return DWORD(InterlockedCompareExchange((long*)p, nNew, nOld)) == nOld; 
}
inline bool CAS(volatile QWORD* p, const QWORD nOld, const QWORD nNew) { 
  Assert(IsAlign64(p)); 
  return QWORD(InterlockedCompareExchange64((LONGLONG*)p, nNew, nOld)) == nOld; 
}
inline bool CAS(volatile PVOID* pp, const void *pOld, const void *pNew) {
  Assert(IsAlign64(pp)); 
  return PVOID(InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(pp, (LPVOID)pNew, (LPVOID)pOld)) == pOld; 
}
```